# Promotional Banner In Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, banner-slider, promotional-banner

I have Banner Slider extension on my website. I would like to add Promotional Banner that appears for some customer after login. For this, is there any extension or need to customize that slider?

Answer (score 0):

put this on where you show banner.  template file if you want to show after login login or not

```
<?php 
        if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
            //logged in  show banner slider here... put your code here 
        }
?>
```

if you want to show some specific customer group. e.g  General, wholesale. etc

```
$groupname = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($customerGroupId)->getCustomerGroupCode();

if($groupname='General'){
  do this...  or show banner /code here..
}
```

if want to show to  specfic customer by name or other attributes . find customer data

```
$customer_data=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
echo "<pre>" print_r($customer_data);
```

Comment: thanks, but I want to show the slider to all but the promotional banner created for that slider to some specific customers.

Comment: specific means particular customer group or customer name..

Comment: we can try for both

Comment: can you share your code ..  or put these validation(above code)  in your  extension controller   so it can be visible to particular

Comment: check within banner loop and get banner id or title to find that banner

Comment: But how can I assign customer group to a particular banner from admin side there is no this kind of option in this extension.

Comment: either u have to create extension to provide option or do custom code in template file.. share some code where slider output